# labeling segments of data based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have an indexed pandas dataframe with values like so:

```
data = {'ID':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'column1': [15, 16, 17, 14, 13, 5, 3, 2, 1.9, 1.2, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'column2': [10, 11, 12, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]
    }


     ID  column1  column2
0    1     15.0     10.0
1    1     16.0     11.0
2    1     17.0     12.0
3    1     14.0     13.0
4    1     13.0     13.5
5    1      5.0     14.0
6    1      3.0     14.5
7    1      2.0     15.0
8    1      1.9     16.0
9    1      1.2     17.0
10   1      1.0     18.0
11   1      0.8     19.0
12   1      0.5     20.0
13   1      0.5     20.0
14   1      0.5     20.0
15   1      0.5     20.0
16   1      0.5     20.0
17   1      0.5     19.0
18   1      0.5     18.0
19   1      0.5     17.0
20   1      0.5     16.0
21   1      1.0     15.0
22   1      2.0     14.0
23   1      3.0     13.0
24   1      4.0     12.0
25   1      5.0     11.0
26   1      6.0     10.0
```

I want to label the rows based on the following conditions:

1. In `column1`, from the beginning until just before we first encounter a
   value `<=2`, **AND** when `column2` is `>13`, label as `Pre_Start`
2. When `0.5 < column1 <= 2` **AND** `< column2 <= 19` label as `Start`
3. When `column1 <= 0.5` **AND** `column2 >= 19` label as `Steady`
4. When `column1 <= 0.5` **AND** `14 < column2 < 19` label as `Ramp`
5. When `column1 > 0.5` **AND** `column2 < 19` label as `End`

Such that the resulting dataframe would be something like this:

```
   ID  column1  column2      Label
0    1     15.0     10.0  Pre_Start
1    1     16.0     11.0  Pre_Start
2    1     17.0     12.0  Pre_Start
3    1     14.0     13.0  Pre_Start
4    1     13.0     13.5  Pre_Start
5    1      5.0     14.0  Pre_Start
6    1      3.0     14.5  Pre_Start
7    1      2.0     15.0      Start
8    1      1.9     16.0      Start
9    1      1.2     17.0      Start
10   1      1.0     18.0      Start
11   1      0.8     19.0      Start
12   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
13   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
14   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
15   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
16   1      0.5     20.0     Steady
17   1      0.5     19.0       Ramp
18   1      0.5     18.0       Ramp
19   1      0.5     17.0       Ramp
20   1      0.5     16.0       Ramp
21   1      1.0     15.0        End
22   1      2.0     14.0        End
23   1      3.0     13.0        End
24   1      4.0     12.0        End
25   1      5.0     11.0        End
26   1      6.0     10.0        End
```

I am able to successfully apply a grouped filter by defining a function start index using `numpy` like

```
def filter_group(group):
start_index = np.argmax(group['column1'].values <= 2)
return group.iloc[start_index:]
```

and calling the function using the `apply` clause:

```
filtered_df = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(filter_group).reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, I can't get it to work with multiple conditions.
Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `np.select`

Comment: @Corralien would that identify the first instance of reaching the condition combination? Also, how do I combine the condition in the clause? Would it be something like: `start_index = np.select((group['column1'].values <= 2) & (group['column1'].values > 0.5))` ?

Comment: *When column1 <0.5 AND column2 > 19 label as Steady*? Maybe <= 0.5?

Comment: *When column1 > 0.5 AND column2 < 14 label as End*? Why row 22 and 23 are End?

Comment: Please check your conditions and your output.

Comment: @Corralien. You are correct. Sorry about that. I have updated my conditions to reflect properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to define labels and then modify them to detect the Pre_Start state:

```
def label_group(df):
    c1 = df['column1']
    c2 = df['column2']
    conds = [(0.5 <= c1) & (c1 <= 2) & (c2 > 14),  # Start
             (c1 < 0.5) & (c2 > 19),  # Steady
             (c1 < 0.5) & (14 <= c2) & (c2 <= 19),  # Ramp
             (c1 > 0.5) & (c2 < 14)]  # End
    choices = ['Start', 'Seady', 'Ramp', 'End']

    labels = np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=choices)
    labels = pd.Series(labels, index=df.index)
    labels[:((c1 <= 2) & (c2 > 13)).argmax()] = 'Pre_Start'

    return labels.to_frame()
    
df['Label'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(label_group).droplevel('ID')
```

Note: conditions are not clear, maybe you can check them.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!. It works, but I had to include `group_keys=True` to the `groupby` clause